# How to find size of M365 search index?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, index, m365

I came across below article and saw that there is a limitation on maximum number of on-premises items that can be indexed in M365.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search-limits

Is there a limit on size of those indexed items as well or is it just the count that matters?

Also, is there a way if we can find out the size of M365 index? My doubt is, if M365 index takes space out of 1TB tenant storage or is it separately stored?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a limit on size of those indexed items as well or is it just the count that matters?

There are the three first limits listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search-limits that apply for each file.

There does not seem to be any limits for all files taken together.